# CCITTFaxDecode image in pdf renders in chrome fine, but acrobat, mupdf, xpdf, ghostscript all have issues

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, chromium, ghostscript, acrobat

I am having an issue with some 3rd party generated pdf files, which contain scans of documents, the object in the pdf document is defined:

```
11 0 obj
<<
/Subtype /Image
/DecodeParms
<<
/K -1
/EndOfBlock false
/Rows 2208
/Columns 1697
>>
/Type /XObject
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode
/Width 1697
/Height 2208
/BitsPerComponent 1
/Length 76057
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Interpolate true
>>
```

Now, chrome can render the PDF with no issues, whereas the other pdf manipulation utilities I've tried: ghostscripts, imagemagick, mupdf, xpdf, etc. either render a truncated image or complain about the file. For instance ghostscript and Acrobat, report:

**** Error: File has insufficient data for an image.

But, clearly chrome can workaround whatever issue there is.

Can someone detail which library or code chrome or chromium uses to decode CCITTFax images? Perhaps by analyzing that code, I can patch or update ghostscript to use that library, and then I'll be able to use gs to re-encode the documents.

There are quite a view posts in Adobe forums about recent versions of Acrobat DC having issues with PDFs  that used to work, but those same posts indicate that recent updates to Acrobat fixed any reported issues, but in my case, even though I'm using the latest version of Acrobat, the PDF in question does not render.

Comment: That looks much more like a Ghostscript error than an Acrobat one, I don't believe I've ever seen Acrobat say anything like that....Does Ghostscript render it the same as Chrome ? Chrome might simply be not complaining, Ghostscript's PDF interpreter deliberately gives Warnings when it finds problems, even when it works around the problems. Your best bet is probably to share an example file. Given that almsot every consumer complains, and they probably all have different implementations of Fax Decoding, I'd have to guess there's something significantly wrong with the PDF file.

Comment: Right, without an example file this is pure guesswork.

Comment: My guess would be that it all comes down to width/columns being an odd number and padding handled differently. Had something similar with another type of image.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, unfortunately I can't share the PDF.

Chrome renders the pdf perfectly - the other clients either don't render it all, or render a truncated version of it.

I agree that there is probably something wrong with PDF, but that doesn't explain how chrome can work around the issue.

My guess there is a common library in ghostscript, imagemagic, etc. that results in them all behaving the same way.

Comment: *"that doesn't explain how chrome can work around the issue"* - PDF viewers are not PDF validators. Quite the contrary actually, they often try and ignore errors in PDFs. Depending on used libraries and arbitrary implementation decisions, the sets of errors they ignore differ. As an aside, if *"Can someone detail which library or code chrome uses to decode CCITTFax images?"* is your main remaining question, you should probably add some Chrome related tags.

Comment: If you cannot share one of your current files, create a new one without that limitation. You have access to that 3rd party library and know how to tell if it's a problematic file or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on adding the chrome / chromium tags. I can't generate the problematic pdfs, because they are coming from a third party document scanning / server service and it's only a small subset of the documents that have the problem.

Comment: How about asking that third party to fix their service?

Answer (score 0):

I found some [evidence](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/2ca8c5037021c9d2ecc00b787d58a31ed8fc8bcb/third_party/libwebp/imageio/tiffdec.c#L262) that Chromium uses LibTiff which makes sense since most implementations use it.  Though not every implementation uses the same version and some have their own tweaks to it so you may see differences between PDF viewers when displaying such images.

Generally Acrobat shows that error when there's not *enough* data for the image.  Based on the image dimensions, color space representation, and bit depth you can calculate the size the stream *should* be for the image data (when not compressed), if what is present in your stream is smaller than that you would see such an error.

What some PDF viewers do is fill in the missing data with some default color, some error out, and some just use whatever nonsense is in memory at the moment to fill in the remaining portion.